# One query that will work for getting Article Owners across all Knowledge article categories?

Tags: apex, soql, community, knowledge, articles

I need to query CreatedById field on Article. I tried using query from below, where 'articleId' represents 'recordId' from article page in community.

```
SELECT CreatedById,Id FROM KnowledgeArticle where Id = :'articleId'
```

It seems to me, that i am doing something wrong, i cannot get CreatedById from above query.
The last thing i came up with is, to access articles i will need to access certain category first, so i will need to query different Objects (depending on category, ***Object_Name__ka***) Is there any workaround?

Comment: Why can't you get `CreatedById`? Do you get an error? If so please include the message here ***verbatim***.

Comment: `Sorry, no records returned.` Seems to me that i'm querying wrong object..

Comment: Did you try querying `Object_Name__ka`? Are you sure there are actually records?

Comment: Yeah, there are records, its coming to my mind now that maybe 'recordId' does not represent the 'Id' in Object_Name__ka table.

Comment: You're supposed to substitute the actual value. No record would ever have an actual id of `'articleId'`.

Comment: Yeah sure. 'ka03B05231004r1QAA' this Id would represent a recordId from Article Page i am trying to query. Also i found some articles that have first 3 characters 'ka1' or 'ka2' which differs from this 'ka0'  starting characters reserved for Knowledge Articles, Do you have any idea why they would start differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in regards to the Id values themselves, you can determine the specific type you need to query by using a script like the following:

```
Id dummyId = Id.valueOf('ka0'.rightPad(15, '0'));
system.debug(dummyId.getSObjectType());
```

So if that yields `Some_Article_Type__ka`, you would query:

```
SELECT CreatedById FROM Some_Article_Type__ka WHERE Id = 'ka0...'
```

You can run that script in `Execute Anonymous`, which you can get to via the `Developer Console`. The same process would apply for `ka1`, `ka2`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Article belongs to specific Article Type object.

To retrieve the `CreatedById`, you need to retrieve from Knowledge Article version object which end with `_kav`

```
SELECT Id,Title,UrlName,Summary,KnowledgeArticleId, CreatedById 
FROM Custom_Artile_Type__kav 
WHERE PublishStatus ='Online' AND Language ='en_US'
AND KnowledgeArticleId = 'kA2160000005CpjCAE'
```

Moreover, there are also restriction firing the SOQL query:

**Implementation restriction:**

> When querying the Custom_Artile_Type__kav object, 
>   you must filter using the following syntax:

1. Id = [single ID], Id IN [list of ID's] or Language = [language ISO code] or PublishStatus = [status]
2. In addition Language is only permitted in a top-level AND condition.

To retrieve Data Categories, you need to query from `__DataCategorySelection`

```
SELECT Id, DataCategoryGroupName, DataCategoryName, ParentId
FROM Custom_Article_Type__DataCategorySelection
```

**Again restriction**

> By the way, we cannot filter on `DataCategoryGroupName, DataCategoryName` in the above SOQL query.

So, filter and matching should have to be done in apex coding.

For more information, refer [Articles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_knowledge.htm)

[image: Knowledge relationship]

Comment: Note that `__kav` is `KnowledgeArticleVersion`, whereas `__ka` is `KnowledgeArticle`.

Comment: correct you are, updating ans