# API Issue with SOQL for Knowledge

Tags: soql, knowledge

I have a Knowledge object which I'm trying to run a SOQL against.

[image]

Running `SELECT Title FROM Knowledge__kav`, I receive:

```
Got a RESTError(status=Bad Request, code=ERR-0002, message=[ValidationError{field='', value=, error='The request is not correct: https://****.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/query.json?&q=SELECT+Title+FROM+Knowledge__kav', exception=Optional.of(java.lang.Throwable: The request is not correct: https://****.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/query.json?&q=SELECT+Title+FROM+Knowledge__kav)}])
```

A query such as `SELECT Id FROM Account` runs fine. The user running this is a system administrator. Any suggestions?

Comment: Endpoint should be .../qyery/... instead ../query.json/...and also while making query always add filter for publishstatus and language...

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_knowledge_support.htm), the endpoint to access Knowledge resources follows the URL pattern as  `<prefix>/support`.

Also, these APIs are available since release 38.0. Additionally refer to the available resources while using Knowledge resources.

```
{
    "dataCategoryGroups" : "/services/data/vxx.0/support/dataCategoryGroups",
    "knowledgeArticles" : "/services/data/vxx.0/support/knowledgeArticles"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, a predicate (`WHERE`) is required for Knowledge objects.

```
Error message: [{"message":"Implementation restriction: When querying the Knowledge__kav object, you must filter using the following syntax: Id = [single ID], Id IN [list of ID's] or Language = [language ISO code]. In addition Language is only permitted in a top-level AND condition.","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]
```

---

The SOQL would then be:

```
SELECT Id, Title FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Language ='en_US' AND PublishStatus = 'Draft'
```

The ER diagram [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/171039/48830) was also valuable in understanding the Knowledge object relationships.

Also, there are restrictions on `PublishStatus` explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BZngIAG).